# Adaptive thresholding on image causing data loss

Tags: python, image, opencv

I am determining adaptive threshold using OTSU and then using determined threshold to convert image to black & white. On this processed image I want to carry out further steps of determining density of each circle, but my black & white image is over corrected and resulting in data loss. Any suggestions on how to tweak adaptive threshold.

```
im_gray = cv2.imread(img, cv2.CV_LOAD_IMAGE_GRAYSCALE)
(thresh, im_bw) = cv2.threshold(im_gray, 128, 255, cv2.THRESH_BINARY | cv2.THRESH_OTSU)
img_bw = cv2.threshold(im_gray, thresh, 255, cv2.THRESH_BINARY)[1]
```

[image]
[image]

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Try [adaptiveThreshold()](http://docs.opencv.org/modules/imgproc/doc/miscellaneous_transformations.html?highlight=adaptivethreshold#cv.AdaptiveThreshold) from openCV, It will calculate the threshold based on the intensities in the *window*. It seems that the OTSU method doesn’t work as expected in your case since adaptiveThreshold uses just an average (minus a constant) and works better (see image below) than OTSU that uses a more optimal criterion.

It is also not clear what is a spatial extent of the OTSU. If it is a whole image, then it should fail since the right side of the image is more blurred than the left and thus dark is washed out on the right. The adaptive threshold makes calculations in a window so it is **locally adaptive.** Note that the last two parameters in the function below are the size of the window and the value to subtract from the average when forming a threshold.

```
adaptiveThreshold(I, dst, 255, ADAPTIVE_THRESH_GAUSSIAN_C, THRESH_BINARY, 21, 15);
```

You may get better results when putting together OTSU and locally adaptive properties. However, the white color is typically oversampled and this causes a bias in the estimate. It is better to sample on the both sides of the gradient to get equal samples of white and dark. It is even better to take into account connectivity and color when thresholding, see [grab cut](http://docs.opencv.org/modules/imgproc/doc/miscellaneous_transformations.html?highlight=grabcut#cv2.grabCut);

Finally, the loss of information is always inevitable during thresholding. 
[image]

Comment: Thanks @ Vlad! I am getting much better results with adaptiveThreshold. After adaptiveThreshold I ran OTSU but didn't see much difference in outcome. How did you find come up with constants 21 & 15 ? Is there advantage of using THRESH_BINARY over THRESH_BINARY_INV  or it's just personal preference?

Comment: Well the furst threshold as I mentioned is a size of the window. It should be kept at about twice the stroke width of your drawing for representative sampling. The second value, that is subtracted from window average in order to calculate threshold prevents noise to pop up at places with background only. Play with them to get a feel of what's going on.